# Recycle numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to reuse the values of a `numpy` array to a certain length:

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> x.make_longer(7)
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1])
```

(Just as a side note, `R` [does this implicitly](https://gist.github.com/njtierney/693555beafc25cee223340a129628327) when trying to perform operations on vectors of different length. So maybe numpy does too?)

Comment: Use `np.resize`.

Comment: Yes! That's it. Thanks. Couldn't find it anywhere. I've obviously got my terminology wrong.